# Tomcat webapp hangs

Tags: java, tomcat, jstack

My webapp started to hang recently. I have managed to use jstack to take its thread dump when it was hanging. The dump is included [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mossaab0/f8b4bed4fa950e273af7/raw/tomcat8-jstack).

With the exception of one `IN_NATIVE` thread, all of the others are `BLOCKED`.

Any hint what could be the cause?

Comment: That's a pretty good trick. It looks like you're running on a Mac. Have you done any OS/Java upgrades recently? You may be falling afoul of increased security measures on Macs, although it's not something I've noticed when running Tomcat on mine.

Comment: This is running on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I often run `a apt-get upgrade`, but am not sure this is related to the problem.

Comment: My bad. I misinterpreted javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(java.lang.String)

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling GC logging, I found that Full GC starts to happen frequently at the time when the app hangs. It is likely that I have a memory leak. Its cause is a different question, though.

Comment: you can take a heapdump and analyze it with Eclipse MAT for instance

Comment: Taking the heapdump fails because of this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044416